# Why is this not a Shopping Question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, not-constructive

I noticed the question [What C# Mocking Framework to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359/what-c-sharp-mocking-framework-to-use) because of its high score. It also seems to have a good list of frameworks and has 20 answers.

That seems to fit the pattern of a "Shopping Question". Should it be closed?

It does seem to have some good content, though. Maybe close but don't delete? Almost a historical lock.

Comment: I'd argue historical lock, for a question from 2008 ;)

Comment: Is every old question that has a lot of votes "Historical Lock" worthy? There's no useful information in any of the answers. It's a worthless question.

Comment: Not every question, no, but I felt there were useful answers there. Feel free to disagree about that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was asked back when the site was young.

> asked Sep 1 '08 at 1:57

The type of questions that were allowed was different back then.

I suspect that now you've brought the question to the attention of the users here on MSO it'll get closed (and probably a historical lock) very quickly.

Comment: I actually didn't notice the date!

Comment: @JohnSaunders - you have to go searching for it in the question history as it's Community Wiki.

Answer (score 3):

That question is a 'shopping' question, and would not survive today. That having been said, I'm not for deleting it because:

- It's really old.  We allowed questions like that back then. We do not now.
- It has quite a few inbound links.
- It has a massive number of views.
- It has useful information in it.

As such, I've placed a historical lock on the question.

Comment: That is a great solution. Could you do the same for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645008/what-are-the-basic-clearcase-concepts-every-developer-should-know/645771#645771 ? It is part of my resume (http://careers.stackoverflow.com/vonc) and it would be a pity to see it go.

Comment: @VonC It has been done.

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but could you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/3597747/6309? I am (again) scarred of that question being simply deleted, while it is also part of my resume (http://careers.stackoverflow.com/vonc) and is a very important question for anyone wanting to tinker with DVCS (Distributed Version Sontrol System) in enterprise. Locking it would be a relief.

Comment: @VonC I can't do that with this question unilaterally.  It's almost irrelevant now (With the state of DVCS being what it is); it has a low number of views; no inbound links; and it's primarily an opinion piece. That having been said, you wrote a great answer.  I think you should bring up a meta question asking the community to preserve it, as well as bring up that some questions are used on resumes, and that should have an effect on whether or not something is deleted.  That's a discussion worth having (I'd focus on the latter; but the former is important too).

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you for having given that question a look.

Comment: ... and question posted on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173051/6309